# Node express session variables different browsers the same result - why?

Tags: node.js, session-variables

I am writing chat program and don't know how to store names of the users. When I store it in to `session.name` it has the same value in every browser I run. Is it possible to do that without using database ?

This is how I do it:

```
 var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore,
 sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
```

and then I just store value:

```
 sessionStore.nickname=nickname
```

now I run browser fill nickname and send it to server. Then open another browser and it already has that value - - I need different values for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain from the question (even the edited version) if you're modifying the `sessionStore` or the `session`. The above code indicates you're modifying the `sessionStore`, which *should* be the same for all requests. To add values to an individual session, assuming you are also using Express, you need to modify the HTTP request's `session` variable. In Express 2.x this is done with `request.session.nickname = nickname;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check it - the docs on express sometimes is not clear for me unfortunatelly .